# OpenGL error 0x0506 in DrawSegment 190

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I created an Xcode Project, where I use cocos2d as a static library (I don't use the template).

To incorporate cocos2d in my storyboard, I followed the tutorial here: [cocos2d & storyboards](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/)

As a result I setup `CCDirector` by using the `CCViewController` class described in the tutorial.

Everything works fine, except every now and then the console spits out a number of OpenGL errors like:

```
OpenGL error 0x0506 in DrawSegment 190
```

My `CCGLView` is created like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
CGFloat width;
CGFloat height;

if (rect.size.width > rect.size.height)
{
    width = rect.size.width;
    height = rect.size.height;
}
else
{
    width = rect.size.height;
    height = rect.size.width;
}

CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

What are these OpenGL errors, and how can I fix them? If I use the template I don't have these problems.

Comment: Error 0x506 is "Invalid Framebuffer Operation". (Defined in OpenGL/gl.h and OpenGL/glext.h.) It means that you haven't set up your framebuffer properly. You need to ensure that you have a valid, complete framebuffer before doing your OpenGL drawing. I don't know cocos2d, so I'm not sure if there are steps you need to take there to make it happen or if you need to just set up your own. [Here's the documentation on how to set up your own.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html)

Comment: I imagine there is something really simple in my setup that is incorrect. I don't think I will be able to sort it out myself by combing through the entire documentation, since I am not doing anything directly with openGl - all my code calls only cocos2d apis. The problem should be in the code above, or in how CCDirector is setup in my view controller.